# Multiple client for one private key to ssh into the server

Tags: server, ssh

I now connect to my Ubuntu server with a rsa key pair from my desktop! But I am not sure what to do to connect from my laptop to the server!!! Do I need to create another key pair? Can I simply copy the private key from one computer to the other?

What is the best practice here?

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either method will work; personally I prefer to create one key per device, to mitigate damage if one device/key gets compromised (just revoke access for this key; no need to do anything for the others).